# What are @PAGE and @PAGEOFF symbols in IDA?

Tags: ida, disassembly

[image]

The above is the disassembly of a 64 bit ARM firmware image. Does anybody know what those `@PAGE` and `@PAGEOFF` symbols mean?

Comment: These are assembler directives to calculate the offset at link time http://stackoverflow.com/q/38711058/4603507

Comment: the image is not showing; reupload it or, even better, just paste the text as a code block.

Comment: I can see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngBHx.png

Comment: hm yeah, it appeared now. but it's still better to [use text instead of screenshots](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: I know that text would be searchable, but rendering could get destroyed.

Comment: I don't think rendering is relevant to the question asked.

Comment: You are more familiar with IDA than probably anyone else out here. I thought it'd help someone who is not familiar to relate to the context. Screenshot help at times. Regarding searching, the keywords, i.e. `PAGE` and `PAGEOFF` are already there in the question title. It hardly matters if the assembly code is searchable or not.

Answer (score 17):

in AArch64, all instructions are 32-bit long. Obviously, this is not enough to encode 64-bit addresses which AArch64 may need to process. So there's two options:

1. use 64-bit pointers placed in the constant pool near the instruction and load them with the  `LDR` instruction. This is doable but such pointers need to be updated (relocated) if the image is loaded at a non-default address.
2. Use PC-relative addressing to load addresses at a fixed offset from the current location (PIC code). This is the more common approach but the offset is still limited by the instruction size. So ARM designers came up with a clever hack: use two instructions to allow for a much wider range.

The ADRP instruction loads the address of the 4KB *page* anywhere in the +/-4GB (33 bits) range of the current instruction (which takes 21 high bits of the offset). this is denoted by the `@PAGE` operator. 
then, we can either use `LDR` or `STR` to read or write any address inside that page or `ADD` to to calculate the final address using the remaining 12 bits of the offset (denoted by`@PAGEOFF`).

So basically you can consider those instruction pairs as if the last one directly accesses the final address of the location before the `@` and you can ignore the suffixes if you don't plan to reassemble the file.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003338/llvm-arm64-assembly-getting-a-symbol-label-address